# Python write to a file r

Tags: python, file, text-files

I am trying to write some basic lines to a text file using Python 3.3.2 (complete beginner here).Not sure why a number returns after the write command line. The number seems to be the length of the string. The string does get stored into the new text file and everything else seems to be okay.

Also :

```
>>> f=open('testfile.txt','w')
>>> f.write('this is line 1\n')
15
```

So, the number '15'.. not sure what it means. Every line I write would return an integer.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think you could make your question a lot better if you edited it to include a question.  What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 2):

From [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> `f.write(string)` writes the contents of string to the file, **returning
>   the number of characters written**.

Comment: Is there way to write it without returning the number of characters written?

Comment: @user2777262 You shouldn't worry about it, you're seeing those numbers because python shell echoes back the return value. Normal script execution will not print these things, unless you don't use : `print(f.write(string))`

Comment: @user2777262 In the python shell, when you execute a command the return value is shown to the screen.  If you were to do this in a script this would not be printed.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to write this would be

```
print('this is line 1', file=f)
```

Because it is more flexible (it takes any input type, not just `str`) and it automatically adds the newline character.  As an added bonus, it won't echo anything in the python shell.